# Solution is nonsense: Prove that if $||x-y|| \geq k||T(x)-T(y)||$ then $T$ need not be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

For all vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $T: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k > 0$, if $||x-y|| \geq k||T(x)-T(y)||$ then $T$ not be invertible.

The solution doesn't make sense. They first choose a $T$ that is non invertible and show that it satisfies the equality shown above.

This doesn't prove the fact that if the equality is true, then $T$ might not be invertible. It just shows that if $T$ is not invertible, then the inequality is true, the other way. How can they do this?

Comment: I thing the correct statement is "if $\|x-y\|\ge k\|T(x)-T(y)\|$ then $T$ is not necessarily invertible". Then the shown solution makes sense.

Comment: @Masacroso Like I said, this proves the other direction, not the direction that is wanted. How does that make sense?

Comment: Trying to make some sense of the wording, which I find confusing, I'd say the solution is logical: they show that there is a non-invertible $\;T\;$ which fulfills the condition... did you mean anything else?

Comment: @DonAntonio That's exactly what I meant, but this should show the reverse direction, that if T is non invertible, then the equality holds. Not that if the equality is true, T might not be invertible

Comment: I think that what was probable meant is something that I'd write as: "Show that if ....so and so... then T **is not necessarily** invertible". For me, this is the same as: show there is a non-invertible $\;T\;\$ which fulfills the condition . Again, your wording is, imo, pretty confusing...and there is no straight and reverse direction, but only one.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Which part of my wording is confusing? So, if you say that "if this then T might not be this", is the same thing as saying "If T is not this, then this"??

Comment: @Goldname: no. "if *blah* then T need not be *whatsit*" means that there exists at least one $T$ which is not *whatsit* such that *blah* holds of $T$. I.e., *whatsit*ness is not not a necessary condition for *blah*ness. To prove this you exhibit a counter-example.

Comment: @Goldname Exactly what Rob wrote. it is not that it is the same, but, as I think I wrote, I think **that** is what could be meant with that confusing wording.

Comment: what it says is that your given condition is not sufficient to guarantee that your operator is invertible. It may or may not be.

Comment: Ok, I see now that my interpretation was wrong. Thanks

Comment: @DonAntonio Is it possible for me to choose a y and T such that T(y) = 0?

Comment: @Goldname Of course, why not? As long as the operator is linear and the condition is fulfilled you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @DonAntonio Actually, I don't think it proves the for all scenario, so this wouldn't be valid right?

Comment: @Goldname It seems like you haven't yet understood the point here: the **whole scenario** here is to find **one single non-invertible** map that fulfills the condition...that's all!

Answer (score 2):

Let be $P(T)$ the property
$$\|x-y\|\ge k\|T(x)-T(y)\|$$
and $I(T)$ "$T$ is invertible".
The title says
$$\neg(\forall T: P(T)\implies I(T)),$$
or equivalently
$$\exists T: P(T)\land\neg I(T),$$
an this can be proved showing **one** noninvertible $T$ what has the property $P$.

About

> They first choose a $T$ that is non invertible and show that it satisfies the equality shown above.

this is *exactly* $\exists T: P(T)\land\neg I(T)$.

> This doesn't prove the fact that if the [in]equality is true, then $T$ might not be invertible. It just shows that if $T$ is not invertible, then the inequality is true, the other way.

*False*. Showing **one** $T$ that verifies $P(T)$ and $\neg I(T)$ proves *again* $\exists T: P(T)\land\neg I(T)$, never $\forall\cdots$